# ZedGraph - I am looking for an example of using a DateTime

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am looking for an example of using a datetime field on a zedgraph 
linechart X-Axis.

Edit - And how do I set the XAxis max scale

```
myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = 12;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to convert the DateTime variables to [XDate](http://web.archive.org/web/20080924055001/http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=What_is_an_XDate_struct%3F) structs. You can create a method like this:

```
public XDate ConvertDateToXdate(DateTime date)
{
  return new XDate(date.ToOADate);
}
```

[Here is an example](http://web.archive.org/web/20081002210147/http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Hi-Low-Close_Demo) of a chart using the XDate structs

Answer (score 11):

Having had the same problem recently, I discovered that the above answer isn't actually correct. The sample code simple casts an XDate() to a double.

However, the sample does highlight what you need to do. I still use DateTime.ToOADate(), but with the addition of the following code, I get to see times (in HH:MM:SS format):

```
pane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
pane.XAxis.Scale.MajorUnit = DateUnit.Hour;
pane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "T";
```