# zedgraph C# datetime how to?

Tags: c#, graph, zedgraph

I'm reading a MySQL database where a table has bid, ask, price_datetime (where price_datetime is down to the second). I'm trying to get 2 line graphs going where the X axis is the price_datetime column and the first line is bid and second is ask.

I can't seem to get this working. I've seen [ZedGraph - I am looking for an example of using a DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512642/zedgraph-i-am-looking-for-an-example-of-using-a-datetime) but it didn't work for me. The example page no longer exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be as in the question you link to. You must convert to XDate before plotting - and of course the axes should be configured to be a Date axis.

I see a lot of the ZedGraph website has 404 errors, but there seems to be a nice tutorial on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx). About half way down the page there is a Date-time axis example.